# Coarsest topology where a function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In topological spaces, a function is defined to be continuous if for every open set, the preimage of $f$ is continuous, which leads to this question:

Let $f:(X, \mathcal{U}_X) \to (Y, \mathcal{U}_Y)$ be a function, what is the coarsest topology $(X, \mathcal{U}_X)$ topology where $f$ is continuous, since $f$ is chosen arbitrary; my guess this would be dependent on the topology $(Y, \mathcal{U}_Y)$, now we can choose:

$$\mathcal U_X = \{f^{-1}(\mathcal U_Y)~:~\mathcal U_Y \text{ is open in Y}\}$$

Now, $f^{-1}$ doesn't necessary need to cover $X$ so we have to choose $\mathcal U_X\cup X\cup \emptyset$, however I am unable to prove that this is indeed a topology, specifically proving that the intersection of finite open sets in $X$ is open, specifically this basically proves it, however it feels somewhat wrong

$$f^{-1}\Big(\bigcap \mathcal U_X \Big)=f^{-1}\Big(\bigcup \mathcal U_X^c \Big) = \bigcup f^{-1}\Big(\mathcal{U}_X^c\Big)=\bigcap f^{-1}\Big(\mathcal U_X\Big)$$

But intuitively this feels wrong... as this would also mean that any intersection of open sets is also open and that wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of an *induced topology*. As $\emptyset=f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ and $X=f^{-1}(Y)$ one does not need exceptions for these cases. As
$$f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f^{-1}( U_i)$$
and
$$f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i\right)=\bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}( U_i)$$
for all families of subsets $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $I$, then proving that
the $f^{-1}(U)$ for open $U\subseteq Y$ form a topology on $X$
is straightforward.

Comment: I think you missed an $f$ in there, however the term $\textit{induced topology}$ made me find out that the inverse image preserves union and intersection and that is enough for me to continue the proof. Thank you.